# Accessing html tag using selenium and CssSelector

Tags: c#, selenium, browserstack

I am trying to access the **order** attribute for the html tag `header > div.column`
Here's my code :  `var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("header > div.column")).GetCssValue("order");`

But I got Object reference issue for GetCssValue . looks like the selected tag doesnt have the attribute "order".

What I am missing here?
Attached screenshot with html code[image]

**UPDATE**
I am using BrowserStack for the testing and when I use Chrome as the browser , it works , but the same code does not work on when I chose IE or Iphone.
Is it because I need to add the IE driver or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

[`order` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) can be not supported depending on the browser.

You may try approaching it differntly - *from the javascript* using the `getComputedStyle()` method:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("header > div.column"))
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).getPropertyValue('order');", element);
```

Comment: So the `.GetCssValue("order");` method wont' work in this case?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker yeah, it may be browser-specific. The `order` property is supported on IE>=11 from what I understand (reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker did it work with the `getComputedStyle()`?

Comment: no it didnt work on that browser , testing on different browsers now